# Hibernate Criteria - Select distinct multiple columns based on other column values

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have an application with some dropdowns for user. I want to perform dropdown filter server side on the basis on some other select values.

The columns are : `brand,version,platform,device,date`

The query I want to perform is:

```
select distinct brand,device,version where platform="this" and date="that"
```

The selected dropdown value goes as a `get`parameter to server to execute this query. Am using `Hibernate Criteria` and `Projections` but not getting the desired results.

Here is my code:

```
public List<String> filterDropDowns(String platform, String device, String date, String brand,
        String version) {
    Criteria crit = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class).createCriteria(Lab.class);

    if (platform == null) {
        crit.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("platform")));
    } else {
        crit.setProjection(Projections.property("platform"));
    }

    if (device == null) {
        crit.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("device")));
    } else {
        crit.setProjection(Projections.property("device"));
    }


    if (date == null) {
        crit.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("date")));
    } else {
        crit.setProjection(Projections.property("date"));
    }


    if (brand == null) {
        crit.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("brand")));
    } else {
        crit.setProjection(Projections.property("brand"));
    }


    if (version == null) {
        crit.setProjection(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("version")));
    } else {
        crit.setProjection(Projections.property("version"));
    }

    List<String> list = crit.list();
    return list;
}
```

And this is how am calling it:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/filter", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<String> filterDropDowns(@RequestParam(value="platform", required=false) String platform,
        @RequestParam(value="device", required=false) String device,
        @RequestParam(value="date", required=false) String dateOfVideo,
        @RequestParam(value="brand", required=false) String brand,
        @RequestParam(value="version", required=false) String version){
    return dropdownService.filterDropDowns(platform,device,date,brand,version);
}
```

The result am getting is the last criteria which I set i.e distinct versions.

How do I achieve the desired result.

Comment: why are you projecting on `date` and `platform` when the query does not?

Comment: There is a check. A user can select any dropdown value and on the basis of selected value, other dropdown values are filtered.